# Azure WebJobs and ApplicationInsights

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-application-insights

I have following code:

```
public static void Main()
    {          

        _servicesBusConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString"];
        _namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(_servicesBusConnectionString);
        _applicationInsightsInstrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appInsightsInstrumentationKey"];

        JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();

        ServiceBusConfiguration serviceBusConfig = new ServiceBusConfiguration
        {
            ConnectionString = _servicesBusConnectionString
        };

        config.UseServiceBus(serviceBusConfig);
        config.LoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory()
            .AddApplicationInsights(_applicationInsightsInstrumentationKey, null)
            .AddConsole();
        config.Tracing.ConsoleLevel = TraceLevel.Off;


        var host = new JobHost(config);

        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
```

and in function:

```
public static async Task ProcessMessages([ServiceBusTrigger(ServiceBusQueueNames.SomeQueueName)]BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage, TextWriter log)
    {
        try
        {

            _log = log;

            _log.WriteLine("WebJob started processing of a message");

            await _log.FlushAsync();}
```

It logs message to console, but not to ApplicationInsights.
Instrumentation key set properly.

Can you please say why it does not log to the ApplicationInsights?

I'v written this code accordingly https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Application-Insights-Integration

Answer (score 0):

first thing to check: is your instrumentation key valid at runtime?

then, if the ikey is what you expect it to be, is it for the resource you expect it to be (you aren't looking at a dev application insights instance but the telemetry is going to a prod instance?)

if you debug this locally, do you see application insights assemblies getting loaded?
do you see console output from application insights with the debugger running?